# How to restrict the content of QInputDialog::getText

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog, qinputdialog

I want to input Hex number with `QInputDialog`, and there is only `getInt`, `getDouble`, `getItem` and `getString`. Only the `getSring` can take in char like "a,b,c,d,e,f". However, is there someway to restrict `getString` only take `0~9||"a-f"`

Comment: Now I realize my custom dialog and use RegExp to restrict the contents.

Comment: Do you want to return a string or a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QSpinBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html) are widgets oriented to obtain numbers from the client input, this has the method [`setDisplayIntegerBase()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#displayIntegerBase-prop) that indicates in which numerical base it is desired to use, in this case it is necessary to use base 16.

So if you look at the method `getInt()` has an internal `QSpinBox` then only that property should be enabled, there is no direct method to get the `QSpinBox`, but we can use the `findchild()` method.

```
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QSpinBox>

static QString getHex(QWidget *parent,
                      const QString &title,
                      const QString &label,
                      int value = 0,
                      int min = -2147483647,
                      int max = 2147483647,
                      int step = 1,
                      bool *ok = Q_NULLPTR,
                      Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::WindowFlags()){
    QInputDialog dialog(parent, flags);
    dialog.setWindowTitle(title);
    dialog.setLabelText(label);
    dialog.setIntRange(min, max);
    dialog.setIntValue(value);
    dialog.setIntStep(step);
    QSpinBox *spinbox = dialog.findChild<QSpinBox*>();
    spinbox->setDisplayIntegerBase(16);

    bool ret = dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted;
    if (ok)
        *ok = ret;
    return spinbox->text();
}
```

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug()<<getHex(Q_NULLPTR, "title", "label", 0x1d, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is just the way I am looking for. Thank you for all help you give me.